# Multiple ckeditor on the same page with same ID

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to be able to replace multiple text area by ckeditor, but they will all have the same ID. Do you know how to do, because now, after loading one editor, it stops.

The actual JavaScript code:

```js
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'advance_editor' );
    </script>
```

Thank you !

Comment: The `id` attribute should be unique, which means you should have only one value of that attribute inside your page.

Comment: How then can I do for load every ckeditor ?